# Replace values in df1 with values in df2 and then assign code in new col if value was replaced

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have df1 thats 1000+ rows and 62 cols. For simplicity it looks similar to this

```
SID  Run ID   TRE ID   Col1   Col2  Col3   Code_Col1   Code_Col2   Code_Col3 
001S  0919A   TRE001     1      2     3        0           0           0
002S  0919A   TRE002     4      5     6        0           0           0
001S  0919A   TRE001R    1      3     2        0           0           0
003S  1010A   TRE003     7      8     9        0           0           0
```

df2 contains values I need to replace in df1

```
SID  Run ID   TRE ID   Col1   Col2  Col3
002S  0919A   TRE002   400     nan   600               
003S  1010A   TRE003   nan     nan   900
```

If the value is replaced I need to change the code for that column to 33. So, my final df1 should look like this

```
SID  Run ID   TRE ID   Col1   Col2  Col3   Code_Col1   Code_Col2   Code_Col3 
001S  0919A   TRE001     1      2     3        0           0           0
002S  0919A   TRE002    400     5    600      33           0          33
001S  0919A   TRE001R    1      3     2        0           0           0
003S  1010A   TRE003     7      8    900       0           0          33
```

I'm pretty lost on how to do this. If I use df.update then I won't know what rows or cols to change the codes cols for

I can't filter by df1["SID"]==df2["SID"] etc. because I'll get the error "Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects".

Comment: is `SID` the only column you are using to match the items,`RUN_ID` and `TRE_ID` are immaterial in this example?

Comment: I need to use all 3 IDs I think because there are duplicates in all 3 ID cold but no (SID,Run ID, TRE ID) duplicates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first add the code cols to the df2 dataframe, then do the update.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'SID': {0: '001S', 1: '002S', 2: '001S', 3: '003S'}, 'Run ID': {0: '0919A', 1: '0919A', 2: '0919A', 3: '1010A'}, 'TRE ID': {0: 'TRE001', 1: 'TRE002', 2: 'TRE001R', 3: 'TRE003'}, 'Col1': {0: 1, 1: 4, 2: 1, 3: 7}, 'Col2': {0: 2, 1: 5, 2: 3, 3: 8}, 'Col3': {0: 3, 1: 6, 2: 2, 3: 9}, 'Code_Col1': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0}, 'Code_Col2': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0}, 'Code_Col3': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0}})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'SID': {0: '002S', 1: '003S'}, 'Run ID': {0: '0919A', 1: '1010A'}, 'TRE ID': {0: 'TRE002', 1: 'TRE003'}, 'Col1': {0: 400.0, 1: np.nan}, 'Col2': {0: np.nan, 1: np.nan}, 'Col3': {0: 600, 1: 900}})

df1.set_index(["SID", "Run ID", "TRE ID"], inplace=True)
df2.set_index(["SID", "Run ID", "TRE ID"], inplace=True)

df2.loc[df2.Col1.notna(), "Code_Col1"] = 33
df2.loc[df2.Col2.notna(), "Code_Col2"] = 33
df2.loc[df2.Col3.notna(), "Code_Col3"] = 33

df1.update(df2)
```

Gives:

```
                      Col1  Col2   Col3  Code_Col1  Code_Col2  Code_Col3
SID  Run ID TRE ID                                                      
001S 0919A  TRE001     1.0     2    3.0        0.0          0        0.0
002S 0919A  TRE002   400.0     5  600.0       33.0          0       33.0
001S 0919A  TRE001R    1.0     3    2.0        0.0          0        0.0
003S 1010A  TRE003     7.0     8  900.0        0.0          0       33.0
```

Comment: Good answer. Beat me to it. I spent too much time trying reconstruct the dataframes perfectly. :)

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you want to update based on the three ID columns. This can be done with `merge` and `groupby`:

```
new_df = df.merge(df2, on=['SID','Run ID', 'TRE ID'],
        how='left', suffixes=['__x','__y'])

# update the code columns
code_cols = [col for col in new_df.columns if col[:4]=='Code']

new_df[code_cols] = new_df.filter(like='__y').notnull()*33

# groupby 
new_df.groupby([x.split('__')[0] for x in new_df.columns],
               sort=False,
              axis=1).last()
```

Output:

```
    SID Run ID   TRE ID   Col1  Col2   Col3  Code_Col1  Code_Col2  Code_Col3
0  001S  0919A   TRE001    1.0     2    3.0          0          0          0
1  002S  0919A   TRE002  400.0     5  600.0         33          0         33
2  001S  0919A  TRE001R    1.0     3    2.0          0          0          0
3  003S  1010A   TRE003    7.0     8  900.0          0          0         33
```

Answer (score 1):

Construct `Code_ColX` from `ColX` of `df2` and `concat` and `update` (note: `X` is the digit)

```
i_cols = ["SID", "Run ID", "TRE ID"]
df1 = df1.set_index(i_cols)
df2 = df2.set_index(i_cols)

df2_Code = df2.notna().replace({True: 33, False: 0}).add_prefix('Code_')
df1.update(pd.concat([df2, df2_Code], axis=1))
df1 = df1.reset_index()

Out[160]:
    SID Run ID   TRE ID   Col1  Col2   Col3  Code_Col1  Code_Col2  Code_Col3
0  001S  0919A   TRE001    1.0     2    3.0        0.0        0.0        0.0
1  002S  0919A   TRE002  400.0     5  600.0       33.0        0.0       33.0
2  001S  0919A  TRE001R    1.0     3    2.0        0.0        0.0        0.0
3  003S  1010A   TRE003    7.0     8  900.0        0.0        0.0       33.0
```